# .htaccess mod_rewrite for dynamic url which has domain names

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, static

I want to convert this url ex:( **example.com/link.php?url=facebook.com** ) to ( **example.com/facebook.com.php** )

How can I do this using .htaccess. Or Is there any other process which will make this job easier ?

I tried by adding the script to .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule url-(.*)\.htm$ link.php?url=$1
```

But its converting the url by adding "url-" ( **example.com/url-facebook.com.php** )

I want to remove "url-" and want to make it look like ( **example.com/facebook.com.php** )

Comment: RewriteRule url-(.*)\.htm$ is not matching with example.com/link.php?url=facebook.com, please double check.

Comment: Why do you have `.html` in your rule?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*link\.php\?url\= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)link\.php\?url\=/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Not too sure how well the above will work it is an edit of something I used to use to remove index.php from a url